# Tomcat 8 - tomcat-users.xml

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, tomcat8

I've installed Tomcat 8 on an AWS instance and it starts and I can access it.
The issue I'm having though is I've added the following to the tomcat-users.xml file but get a 403 error when I try to access the Server Status, Manager App, and Host Manager. I've stopped and restarted Tomcat a couple of times as well as rebooting the AWS instance but to no avail.

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="pswd123"
  roles="manager-gui,manager-status,admin-gui"/>
<user username="tomcattools" password="pswd123"/> 
</tomcat-users>
```

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: What url are using to access manage....https://ec2Instance/manager

Comment: I use the public DNS :8080 to access Tomcat and then I click on the Manager App button on the right and get the 403.

Comment: Strange, try appending this to DNS:8080/manager, so your just adding /manager this should provide form for you to login, try that and see if it gives you the form to login

Comment: Thanks for the input but I still get a 403 - Access Denied. Is there an additional file I should edit and add/change another setting?

Comment: By the way, I'm accessing Tomcat remotely. I'm not running a browser from the same server it's running on. I log into the EC2 instance using Putty and start Tomcat. Then on my local PC I start Chrome and access it there.